# ASP.Net https v/s http

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, http, https

Published a ASP.Net web service in iis 6.0. I am not able to access the service with http protocol. Only https works and its prompting a certificate error. Any solution to make this an unsecured one . I need to access it through http only how?

Comment: what happens when you try to access it over http? i.e. where is that blocked - it could be in IIS, it could be at a network device, etc... Obviously that is local to your environment, so we can't look.

Comment: The page you are trying to view requires the use of "https" in the address.

Answer (score 0):

With the error message from the comments, that sounds like an IIS setting. In IIS, look at the site properties - in particular any "security" tabs etc - you should find there is a checkbox for requiring SSL. If you are sure that it is valid for the **entire site** to be available without SSL (presumably it was checked for a reason...), consider unchecking it. But emphasis: this is for the entire site.

Re the certificate error, that probably means your certificate is either expired or has the wrong host - in the same area there should be an option to change the certificate. To use SSL you will need to obtain a valid certificate.

Answer (score -1):

I removed SSL from directory settings of the application.But it was not working.Then removed the SSL for .asmx file fixed the issue.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but this answer doesn't really address how you 'removed the SSL', which may make it useful for somebody else in the future...